# Apply multiple filters on same column qualifier

Tags: hbase, qualifiers

In my project,i have a condition where i have to apply two `SingleColumnValue` filters on same column qualifier. The two filters are to check if the column qualifier contains the value 'A' or the value 'B'. But, the filter doesn't seems to be working.

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);

SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("data"),               Bytes.toBytes("type"),CompareOp.EQUAL,Bytes.toBytes("A"));
filter2.setFilterIfMissing(true);
filterList.addFilter(filter2);

SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("type"), CompareOp.EQUAL,  Bytes.toBytes("B"));    filter1.setFilterIfMissing(true);
filterList.addFilter(filter1);
```

Is there any mistake in doing so? Is this possible, applying two filters on same qualifer? Are there any alternate solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your filter settings are fine. Could you further elaborate what's the problem? Note that `SingleColumnValueFilter` returns all the columns of a row if the given condition is met. I.e: a row's single column value determines whether to return the entire row or not.
If you just want to retrieve those columns that meet the conditions use `ValueFilter` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to solve the problem discussed above is to use RegexStringComparator.

Create a RegexStringComparator with the needed matches and use it with SingleColumnValueFilter.

Comment: Can you give an example please ?